GitHub Pages with Jekyll remote theme; skin not working
I'm having trouble configuring my GitHub Pages deployment to use jekyll/minima with the dark skin. The problem is that the dark skin isn't applied.
Here's the structure of the repo.

_config.yml
title: <repo-name>

url: "https://silvncr.github.io"
baseurl: "/<repo-name>"

plugins:
  - jekyll-remote-theme

remote_theme: jekyll/minima

minima:
  date_format: "%Y-%m-%d"
  skin: dark


docs/assets/css/style.scss
---
---

@import "{{ site.theme }}";

// other stuff



I've also overridden some HTML files in the _layouts and _includes directories. Both these edits and the custom CSS seem to be working, as well as the minima theme itself; it's just the dark skin that doesn't work.
